# How to create a MDList with text on the left side of each entry and a progress bar on the right side of each entry in KivyMD?

Tags: listview, kivy, listitem, kivymd

So far this is what I have, but when I create an `MDList` and populate it with instances of `CustomListItem`, only the last entry in my `MDList` shows a progress bar.

```
<CustomListItem>:
    MDGridLayout:
        rows: 1
        cols: 2
        MDLabel:
            id: name
        
        MDProgressBar:
            id: progress    
            value: 50
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MDProgressBar`s are all present in the `MDList`, but they are all placed in the same position for some reason. Specifying the size and position of the `MDGridLayout` solves this issue.

```
<ExerciseListItem>:
    MDGridLayout:
        rows: 1
        cols: 2
        size: self.parent.size
        pos: self.parent.pos
        MDLabel:
            id: name
        
        MDProgressBar:
            id: progress    
            value: 50
```

This seems like very strange behavior to me.